# How to share same Input Method across multiple windows in (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing

I want to make all `Windows` open in a Java swing application sharing same language `InputMethod`, that is, changing `InputMethod` in one window will result `InputMethod` changing in every other `Window`.

I have tried to create a single global `InputContext` and override `getInputContext()` of each window to return that Context, but it's not working reliably for some language input methods. Any idea?

Comment: InputContext (doesn't matter what it is) is static, protected, question in this form isn't answerable here, nor for user with 2k rep. point, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JComponents in local variable

Comment: @mKorbel, I am not expected an exact solution here, I am just hoping to hear some general suggestions or hints that point me to right direction. Thanks